# Inserting a record into a a Dbase using a html form (MYSQL/PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, html, database

As the title says i'm trying to insert a record into a mysql database via a html form.

Here is the html form portion of the file: **Addstudent.html**

```
/div>
<div id="main">
    <h2>Add another student?</h2>
    <p>Please fill out the requested fields.</p>
   <form action="Insertstudent.php" method="post">
  StudentId:     <input type="text" name="studentid"><br>
  Password:      <input type="text" name="password"><br>
  Dob:           <input type="text" name="dob"><br>
  Firstname:     <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  Surname:       <input type="text" name="surname"><br>
  Address:       <input type="text" name="address"><br>
  Town:          <input type="text" name="town"><br>
  County:        <input type="text" name="county"><br>
  Country:       <input type="text" name="country"><br>
  Postcode:      <input type="text" name="postcode"><br>
  <input type="Submit">
```

Here is part of the file **Insertstudent.php**

```
<?php
// Insert record using this script

session_start();
include("dbconnect.inc");


// If the form has been submitted
if ($_POST[submit]){
// Build an sql statment to insert a new student to the database
$sql="INSERT INTO student values '" . $_SESSION[id] ."' . '$_POST[studentid]'.'$_POST[password]' . '$_POST[dob]' . '$_POST[firstname]' . '$_POST[lastname]' . '$_POST[house]' . '$_POST[county]' . '$_POST[country]' . '$_POST[postcode]')";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
 ?>
```

The main trouble I'm having is with the Insert script - I'm obviously doing something wrong with that because my database doesn't update.

Thank you in advance to anyone who replies to this - much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try the following syntax for inserting records into your database.

```
INSERT INTO table_name(col1,col2,col3) VALUES(val1,val2,val3);
```

when you make a post request from a mysql page you should be doing something like this.

```
INSERT INTO student(studentid,password,dob,firstname,surname,address,town,country,postcode) VALUES($_POST['studentid'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['dob'],$_POST['firstname'],$_POST['surname'],$_POST['address'],$_POST['town'],$_POST['country'],$_POST['postcode']);
```

but be aware this way you are allowing the users to input malicious code, if you do it like this they could easily do some mischief with your database like, deleting or altering the records. to overcome this you can use a built in PHP function  called [mysql_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

Answer (score 1):

Separate the values to insert by commas, not periods. E.g.:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) VALUES (value1, value2)
```

NOTICE: separate values with commas (,) not periods (.)